# how to fix: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy bug

Tags: flutter, facebook, firebase-authentication

I am using flutter_facebook_auth to login and register my user. Backend - firebase.

```
class FacebookSignInProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
Map<String, dynamic> _userData;

Future<UserCredential> signInWithFacebook(BuildContext context) async {
final LoginResult result = await FacebookAuth.i.login(
    permissions: ['name', 'email', 'user_birthday', 'user_gender'],
);

 if(result.status == LoginStatus.success){
  final userData = await FacebookAuth.i.getUserData(fields: "username, 
email, birthday, gender");
  _userData = userData;

  final OAuthCredential credential = 
FacebookAuthProvider.credential(result.accessToken.token);
  return await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
}
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
    CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (_) => TabScreen()));
notifyListeners();
return null;
}
}
```

This goes to the FB Sorry, something went wrong screen.

[image: facebook_screen]

What bug is this?

Comment: can you add the complete error log? i cant see any getter neither an uid in the code you are sharing!

Comment: I added getUserdata() method and now am getting this error: W/ActivityThread(17419): handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@2c8cbcc
W/v.mongol_revie(17419): Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->getAccessibilityDelegate(). It goes to the Something went wrong Facebook page. Let me edit my question completely.